# Drools rule condition - check if attribute is null

Tags: java, drools

I have a fairly simple case where I want to check in my rule condition whether an attribute is not null.

```
rule "only do action if attribute is not null"
when
    $fact : Fact(attribute!=null, $attribute : attribute)
then
    rulesLogger.debug("Rule fires = " + $attribute);
end
```

I have tracked this through in debug. A Fact is being inserted with the attribute as null but the rule still fires. The console output is as follows.

```
Rule fires = null
```

If I change the condition to `attribute==null` then the rule doesn't fire. So it seems to be doing the exact opposite to what I would expect.

We do have a workaround for this using a function but it's a bit ugly and I can't figure out why it doesn't work in the first place.

```
function Boolean attributeExists(Fact fact)
{
    if(fact.getAttribute() == null)
    {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}

rule "only do action if attribute is not null"
when
    $fact : Fact($attribute : attribute)
    Boolean(booleanValue == true) from attributeExists($fact)
then
    rulesLogger.debug("Rule fires = " + $attribute);
end
```

**EDIT 1**

The drools version is 5.3.0.

The fact is loaded via another rule using `from` and a service method call. I can't see that the fact is invalid because it prints as I would expect to the console and also the manual workaround with a function works as expected. It's a strange one.

**EDIT 2**

I've found a better workaround. If I access the attribute using the getter method then the rule behaves as expected. This looks much better than having to write an extra function but it would still be nice to know why this isn't working when using the property name.

```
rule "only do action if attribute is not null"
when
    $fact : Fact(getAttribute()!=null, $attribute : attribute)
then
    rulesLogger.debug("Rule fires = " + $attribute);
end
```

The Fact class is just a boring POJO. It has no superclass other than Object and implements no interfaces. It's not a JPA entity or anything where there might be a proxy or lazy loading.

Comment: Please add the Drools version and the code for assembling and inserting the Fact objects.

Comment: Do you have a particular hunch or just looking for completeness? The actual code was more complicated than this but I gradually took bits out until I was left with this very simple example and the problem still remained.

Comment: Well, I don't have fond memories for 5.3. That EDIT2 works appears to support my misgivings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some of these. I'm not sure whether D was possible with 5.3.

```
rule "only do action if attribute is not null"
when
  Fact($att: attribute != null)             /* A */
  Fact($att: attribute, eval($att != null)) /* B */
  Fact($att: attribute, attribute != null)  /* C */
  Fact($att: attribute, $att != null)       /* D */
then
  rulesLogger.debug("Rule fires = " + $attribute);
end
```

*An upgrade is highly recommended.* 5.5.0 might be an option where no code breaks but failures like this one are avoided.

Comment: I tried all of these and found that B and D work in addition to my EDIT2 fix using the getter method. So there are three options. I also tried upgrading to 5.5.0 but this didn't fix the problem, although I did notice a lot more useful logging in the console.

Comment: A and C not working is a bug, but you won't get a fix for anything 5.x. - Strange though that 5.5. isn't better. I just googled that there is a 5.6.0-Final; I must have skipped that in favour for 6.0, so that's one last option if you want to use the more natural A and C.